# jquery unable to load div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this piece of code but i am unable to make this work i am unable to load the links

**jquery.js**

```
 $('.menu_top').click(function(){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content_area').fadeOut().load(href).fadeIn('normal');

        $('.menu_top').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });
```

**Index.php**

```
  <a class="menu_top" href="#content_area">LINK 1</a> 
        <a id="content_area"style="display:none;">
         THIS IS LINK ONE 
       </a>
  <a class="menu_top" href="#content_area">LINK 2</a> 
        <a id="content_area"style="display:none;">
         THIS IS LINK TWO
       </a>
```

Comment: load is a ajax function that need a url as a parameter

Comment: What are you expecting to be loaded ? What will URL => `#content_area` load ?

Comment: .load() method accept a url or container preceding with URL. in your case it is only the #content_area. also this is twice in page

Comment: You have two anchor tags with "content_area" as your id, which is invalid. Each id should be unique.

Comment: I think you want to do something like this: $('#content_area').fadeOut().next('a').fadeIn('normal');

Comment: $(this).closest('a') use this,

Comment: U didn't respond yet

Comment: i have used a different solution will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution worked for me 
**Index.php**

```
    <div  class="menu_top" data-target="#content_area1">Link 1</div> 
        <div  class="menu_top" data-target="#content_area2" >Link 2</div> 
        <div  class="menu_top" data-target="#content_area3" >Link3</div> 

<div id="content_area1" class="content_area" style="display:none;"> 
This is link 1
</div>
<div id="content_area1" class="content_area" style="display:none;"> 
This is link 2
</div>
<div id="content_area1" class="content_area" style="display:none;"> 
This is link 3
</div>
```

**Jquery.js**

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
var el=$(this)
$('.menu_top').removeClass('active')
$('.content_area').hide()
  $($(this).data('target')).show('slow', function() {

    $(el).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this).closest('a')` for finding closest anchar after  `class="menu_top"`.

**[Documentation of .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```js
$('.menu_top').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).closest('a').fadeOut().next('a').fadeIn('normal');

    $('.menu_top').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu_top" href="#content_area">LINK 1</a> 
<a id="content_area"style="display:none;">
THIS IS LINK ONE 
</a>
<a class="menu_top" href="#content_area">LINK 2</a> 
<a id="content_area"style="display:none;">
THIS IS LINK TWO
</a>
```